# limit of a sequence (infinity sum)

Tags: sequences-and-series, limits

I have this question about proving that the sequence have non real limit

$$
U_n=1+\dfrac{1}{2}+...+\dfrac{1}{n}
$$
I've proved that $1<U_n<n$ 

is that enough ?or it's wrong 

Thanks for helping

Comment: The inequality $1<U_n<n$ for any $n\geq 2$ is correct, but it does not allow to conclude anything about the convergence or divergence of $U_n$. Something like $U_n\geq \log(n)$, on the other hand...

Comment: Can I ask about another thing I saw that prove by $U_{2^n}$ but I didn't mange to know how to write in that form can u just clarify this point

Comment: have a look at https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cauchy_condensation_test